# Not able to assign model value to a parameter in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I've got a razor page code which I use to display a page.

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string Test {get; set;}
    public class InputModel
    {        
        public List<SelectListItem> QList { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Helper helper = new Helper(_logger, _context);
        var Test = helper.GetTestString();
        var saltyList = helper.GetAllApples();

        Input.QList = saltyList;
    }
}
```

The variable saltyList has 15 values. But I am getting an error :

> {System.ExecutionEngineException: Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.}

Am I missing something? Is it not possible to assign value in Get method or am I missing something?Is there an issue in terms of me not having initialized Input.Qlist to anything before assigning the value? Test works fine but not the InputModel assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the value of Input in the OnGet method. Something like this :

```
public void OnGet()
{
    Helper helper = new Helper(_logger, _context);
    var Test = helper.GetTestString();
    var saltyList = helper.GetAllApples();

    Input = new InputModel
            {   
                QuestionList = questionList
            };
}
```

If you want to bind the value in Get like how you are doing, you might have to use SupportGet= true for Bindproperty.

```
[BindProperty(SupportGet=true)]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)